# How to use HOC and recompose properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback, higher-order-functions, higher-order-components

I just started React recently and read about HOC.

I would like to do something similar to: making a container editable.
My 'solution' (as it's not working properly yet.)

editableRow (HOC):

```
import React from 'react'

import { withStateHandlers, withHandlers, compose } from 'recompose'

const editableRow = () =>
    compose(
        withStateHandlers(
            { isEditing: false, editingId: null },
            {
                toggleEditing: ({ isEditing, editingId }) => entryId => ({
                    isEditing: !isEditing,
                    editingId: isEditing ? null : entryId
                })
            }
        ),
        withHandlers({
            handleSave: ({
                isEditing,
                editingId,
                onEdit,
                onCreate,
                list
            }) => values => {
                console.log('handling...')
                if (isEditing) {
                    const entry = list && list.find(entry => entry.id === editingId)
                    return onEdit(entry.id, values) 
                } else return onCreate(values)
            }
        })
    )

export default editableRow
```

My DataRow:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Button, Checkbox, Icon, Table, Input } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import editableRow from 'hoc/editableRow'

const DataRow = props => 
    <Table.Row>
        {
            props.children
        }
    </Table.Row>

export default editableRow()(DataRow)
```

My component will receive the functions and the states I made with the HOC,
but for some reason I can't pass it anything (like calling the callbacks [onEdit, onCreate]). And isn't there a nicer way to call the handleSave instead of onSubmit={()=>props.handleSave(props1, props2, ...)}

UPDATE:

Well my problem is that I can't send any 'handler' to my component in any way. I tried it like:

```
<Table.Row onClick={()=>props.handleSave(
        false,
        false,
        props.onCreate,
        props.onEditing,
        props.list
    )}>
        {
            props.children
        }
    </Table.Row>
```

But my HOC's handleSave is just using it's own default values. I can't reach them, so I can't pass any handler to it.
My guess is that I making a very basic error somewhere, but don't know where :D

[Like when I save the field. That why I got those onEditing, onCreating event, BUT I even if I pass them my HOC is just using its OWN DEFAULTs instead of the parameters I passed to it]

HELP me guys please to understand how these are working... :D

Comment: Can you please tell what exactly the problem is because the question is very good but I am not able to get your actual problem

Comment: I updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React from 'react'
import {compose} from 'recompose';
import { Button, Checkbox, Icon, Table, Input } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import editableRow from 'hoc/editableRow'

const DataRow = props => {
    const values = {
        isEditing: false,
        editingId: false,
        onEdit: props.onCreate,
        onCreate: props.onEditing,
        list: props.list,
    };

    return (
        <Table.Row onClick={() => {props.handleSave(values)}}>
            {props.children}
        </Table.Row>
    );
}

export default compose(editableRow)(DataRow);
```

Whenever you'll `compose` your component with `HOC` then your HOC will have the `props` which you provided to this component as you're exporting the **composed** component.

So, in your HOC, you can access the `props` passed like this:

```
import { withStateHandlers, withHandlers, compose } from 'recompose'

const editableRow = () =>
    compose(
        withStateHandlers(
            { isEditing: false, editingId: null },
            {
                toggleEditing: ({ isEditing, editingId }) => entryId => ({
                    isEditing: !isEditing,
                    editingId: isEditing ? null : entryId
                }),
                handleSave: (state, props) => values => {
                    console.log('handling...')
                    if (isEditing) {
                        const list = values.list;
                        const entry = list && list.find(entry => entry.id === editingId)
                        return props.onEdit(entry.id, values) 
                    } 
                   return props.onCreate(values)
                }
            }
        ),
    )

export default editableRow;
```

You don't have to use `withHandlers` explicitly when you're using `withStateHandler` which can be used for both `state` and `handlers`. I hope this helps, let me know if you're still stuck.

```
withStateHandler(arg1: an object or a function to set initial state, {
    callback: (state, props) => callbackValues => {
        //call any callback on props
        props.handleSave(); // or props.onCreate() etc.
        //return desired state from here
    }
})
```

Comment: Ohhh that a nice feature. I will have some time in a hours and will be able to test it. Thanks man :)

Comment: You should upvote it and mark it as right answer if you feel that's right and helped you :)